# Error:(40, 13) Failed to resolve: "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-beta1"

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin

I want to add recyclerview to my android project in intellij but when I add it my gradle synced failed and it says:Error:(40, 13) Failed to resolve: "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-beta1".

my gradle file is:

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.saleh.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
}
```

what should I do??

Comment: why you are using beta version of recyclerview?

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had this same problem. And got a solution of this just by changing the order of repositories in biuld.gradle (app). Which really worked for me .

> Replace

```
repositories {

    jcenter()
    google()
 }
```

> By this _

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

This should work fine. Or Try By updating all the support dependencies to the latest version.